# Tips or thoughts on pruning old giant leggy jade?

Tags: pruning, jade

[image]

I have an old leggy jade tree that has a lot of horizontal growing branches. The stems are thick and woody and are already spilling over the sides of the pot, so there's actually only one or two vertical branches. I'd like to get it bushier and grow more horizontal to fill in the gaps.

Looks like I'll have to be pretty aggressive about pruning it back. What do you guys think? Will pruning the horizontal growing branches encourage it to grow upwards? It's also a bit lop sided and the heavier side is what is in the picture.

Comment: There are also some small nubs that look broken off that haven't grown anything in awhile. They're right at the node and the hard cap doesn't seem like it'll come off, so I was thinking of cutting down to the next internode in hopes it'll sprout from there. What do you think?

Comment: I see you have leaves coming off. I snabbed a couple fallen Hobbit Jade https://www.gardenloversclub.com/houseplants/jade-plant/growing-hobbit/ plant leaves a couple years ago, and planted them in silt/sand soil pots. Watering once a week, with about half a sun worth of light. Two years later, I have two prettily formed plants, about 6 to 8 inches tall with good stems, and even branches. From the original plant I expect my clones to max out at about 2 feet (30 cm).

Comment: When was the last time you gave it a bigger pot?